# Rails 6 Singular Routes and CanCanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, cancan, cancancan

I have a Rails 6 app and am using CanCanCan to authorize resources.

For my plural resources CanCanCan has the `load_and_authorize` method which looks in my abilities which resources the user has access to.

But know I want that a user can see its account.

In my user model I have

```
belongs_to :account
```

Where one account can have multiple users.

And in my abilities

```
can [:read], Account, id: user.account_id
```

So the user can access: `/accounts/:id`

But I would like him to access `/account` instead.

So I created a singular resource `resource :account`

But how do i load the account resource now? I was hoping that CanCanCan does that for me. But it seems that ir does not. Is the only solution really to load the resource somehow with `Account.find(id)`? This does not seem like a clean solution since the singular route routes to the plural controller where I have CanCanCan for authorizing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you use something like `current_user.account` to get the account?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things here. First, your routes are entirely independent from your Cancancan resources (Cancancan deals with resources, not routes, even though some of the terminology is the same in both cases.) So, whatever routes you define, that's entirely different from the abilities you have defined for Cancancan.

The next step is to get your abilities set up properly so that your user can get at the right records. And it looks to me that your ability is correct: a user can read Account records when `@account.id` matches `@user.account_id`.

So, you should be able to use `@user.account` and get back the associated Account record via the usual Rails association that you've set up. (I assume that Account `has_many` Users, in the reciprocal of the `belongs_to` association you've set for the User model.)